How to Average Engine Performance: Direct or Weighted?
I’m unsure about which method to use for calculating the average in my analysis. Here’s my setup:
Scenario: I have three new engines (A, B, and C) and two main goals:

To determine the overall performance of each engine individually
(labeled as W for Engine A, X for Engine B, and Y for Engine C)
To calculate the combined overall performance of all three engines
(labeled as Z).

Data Details: Each engine has a different number of data points (e.g., Engine A has 3 data points, Engine B has 12, etc.).
Here's the table (illustration) about engine A data:

where %Efficiency is calculated as:

And here's the expected table to answer my 2nd goals (Z)

The part that I get confused:

For W, X, and Y (individual engine performance):

Method 1: Calculate %Efficiency by averaging directly.
Method 2: Sum the total fuel and electricity produced across the data points, then calculate a new combined L/kWh and use this to calculate %Efficiency.


For Z (overall performance of all engines):

Method 1: same as above
Method 2: same as above
Method 3: Calculate a weighted average of %Efficiency, where the weight for each engine is based on its number of data points.



My Questions:

For W, X, and Y, which method is correct and why?
For Z, which method is correct and why?

Note: Could you keep the explanation simple, as I’m not a statistics or math student :')

Could you be more specific about what you mean by "performance," how you intend to quantify it, and the sense in which engine performance can be "combined"?

By "performance," I'm referring to each engine's efficiency, measured as %Efficiency. For each engine (A, B, and C), I want to measure its individual %Efficiency, which I call W, X, and Y, respectively.
My 2nd goal is to find the most accurate way to reflect the overall performance (efficiency) of the engines as a group/whole (labeled as Z).

But what would a "group" efficiency mean?  Shouldn't that depend on things like the relative frequency of utilization of the engines?

Will keep the answer short, and simple, as requested.
For Q1 (how to compute W,X,Y), sum all the fuel used and kWh produced, and compute the overall %efficiency, just as you did. The reason is that, if you compute the average of the %Efficiencies, this assumes that they were based on the same fule used (i.e. hours of operation). But that is not how your data was collected. So you need to give more importance to the test runs were more fuel was used. So sum all the fuel and kWh first. This is nothing more than the weighted average of %Efficiency, weighted by the fuel used.
Q2 (Z). Use the same approach (Method 2), for the same reason (not all 3 engines were used for the same amount of time/fuel. You mention weighting by the number of data points (which assumes that not all 3 engines had 3 test runs?). There is no need for that; by summing all the fuel/kWh's, you are already doing this (in the end, is there a difference between 10 runs consuming 100l each, or 2 runs consuming 500l each?).\
Now, all of the above assumes that all the test runs were done under sinilar conditions (same external and internal engine temperature, compression ratio, same fuel, etc.; all parameters which would impact fuel consumption and/or energy production). This would seem like good experimantal practice. But if the test runs were under different conditions (intentionally, or accidentally), then you can not use Method 2, and instead have to use Method 1 (unweighted average of the efficiencies).But, if in addition the number of test runs (and thus conditions) was not the same, we would need much more details about the different conditions, test runs, etc. But you may be approaching a point where nothing useful may be done with the data?

Hi, thank you very much for enlightening me. May I ask a follow-up question? If I need to "average the fuel averages" for each engine (from Table Z), should I directly calculate the average (Method 1), or should I use Method 3 instead?

If the conditions of each test run are as identical as you can practically make them, then you just sum (not average) the fuel consumption, and sum the kWh produced, both over all runs for each engine, and then compute the %Efficiency. So Method 2 as well. This will give you the true "observed" %Efficiency. But the issue is that your 2nd table seems to want to compute an average %Efficiency, as if all engines had run for the same amount of fuel/time. Then just average the average %Efficiencies. ...ctd

...ctd. This will weigh the engines with less fuel used more heavily, to give you an estimated average %Efficiency, as if all engines had run for the same amount of fuel/time. This is none of your 3 methods. Now, if the total amount of fuel used for all 3 engines is close, the observed %Efficiency, and the estimated one will be very close. If not, they can be different, and you can report both.
